# Search for a directory on windows command line

Tags: windows

How do I search for a directory on windows command line? I'm looking for the similar behavior to explorer. In explorer, when you type a file it search for files AND directories. I want to do this from the command line. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cmd.exe:

```
dir /AD /S DirName
```

PowerShell 2:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter DirName | ? { $_.PSIsContainer }
```

PowerShell 3:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory -Filter DirName
```